# How to multiply a .txt data file by a constant number?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a .txt file with one column. it is about 8000 numbers.
How can I multiply this column of data by 1000000?

Comment: If the numbers are strictly integers, then `sed 's/$/000000/' file.txt`

Comment: @glennjackman: That looks like an answer. :-]

Comment: What if the numbers are not integers?

Answer (score 24):

You can use [`awk`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/awk.1posix.html) command:

```
awk '{print $1*1000000}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 16):

If the numbers in the file are integers or simple floating-point values, you could use the `numfmt` utility with `--from-unit=` to indicate the desired scaling.

Ex. given

```
$ cat file
1.23
5
3.45
17
6.78
23
```

then

```
$ numfmt --from-unit=100000 < file
123000.00
500000
345000.00
1700000
678000.00
2300000
```

You can add a variety of `printf`-style formating to the output e.g.

```
$ numfmt --from-unit=100000  --format="%'12.2f" < file
  123,000.00
  500,000.00
  345,000.00
1,700,000.00
  678,000.00
2,300,000.00
```

---

Alternatively, with `sed` and `bc`:

```
sed 's/$/ * 100000/' file | bc
```

or (reverse polish variant)

```
sed 's/$/ 100000 * p/' file | dc
```

Comment: Should that be `bc` in the last command or is `dc` something else?

Comment: @PerlDuck `dc` is something else - see for example [How is bc different from dc?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124518/how-is-bc-different-from-dc)

Comment: LOL, I haven't read carefully enough and thought of _polish_ as in _make something shiny_. Ty for explaining.

Comment: Ha, so "reverse polish" is "to make something *less* shiny (more muddy)"? IMO, dc meets that requirement

Comment: See this link, [Wikipedia: Reverse Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) - This became popular in the 1970ies with the HP-35, the world's first handheld scientific calculator, and the following series of calculators.